# How to connect different DB with single application across multiple users

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc, threadpool

So i have a problem. Currently my application connects with single database and supports multi user. So for different landscapes, we deploy different application all together.

I need a solution that my application remains the same (single WAR deployment) but is able to connect to different DB across different landscapes.

For example a user in UK is using same application but underlying DB is in UK and subsequently another user logs in from Bangladesh and he sees the data of DB schema for Bangladesh and so on.

Currently we are creating JDBC connections in a connection pool created out of java and taking the same through out the application. Also we load static datas   in hashmaps during the start up of server. But the same would not be possible with multiple DB since one would overwrite the other static data.

I have been scratching here and there , If some one can point me in the right direction, would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that your application start up and a user's geography are not connected attributes. You simply need to switch / pick correct DB connection while doing CRUD operations for a user of a particular geography.

So in my opinion, your app's memory requirement is going to be bigger now ( than previous ) but rest of set up would be simple.

At app start up, You need to initialize DB Connection pools for all databases and load static data for all geographies and then use / pick  connection & static data as per logged in user's geography.

There might be multiple ways to implement this switching / choosing logic and this very much dependent on what frameworks & libraries you are using.